# How to put reflectbox in newtheorem correctly?

Tags: theorems

Firstly: sorry for my English, I hope, that you'll understand me.
Secondly: I have to use `\reflectbox` in my newtheorem environment. Problem is, that when I put for example `\reflectbox{D}`, letter D is inclined to wrong direction (to the left). Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: That's what happens if you reflect something. You could (depending on your TeX engine) apply some kind of PostScript or PDF sheer transform to a D but perhaps you could give more indication of your system and your actual use case.

Answer (score 6):

As David says in the comments, it's in the nature of the `\reflectbox` command to make a right-leaning *D* lean instead to the left. It would be nice if there existed a "reverse italics" font where italicised letter leant to the left, but I don't know of such a thing.

If you're *only* working with the particular letter "D", then you could exploit the vertical symmetry of that letter, and rotate it 180 degrees instead of reflecting it (when inside an italicised environment like a theorem, that is).

Here is some code to show that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand\D{\reflectbox{D}}

\begin{document}

\noindent $\D$ is true.
\begin{theorem} $\D$ is true.\end{theorem}

\newcommand\DD{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{D}}
\begin{theorem} $\DD$ is true.\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another option is to stop your theorem environment from italicising its contents. This can be done by adding the following two lines to my example code, immediately after the `\usepackage{amsmath}` line:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, glad to help. Please consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark at the top left. This way, this question can be recorded as "solved". `:-)`